# React-Router Blank Page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm still learning to using react-router. I just wondering why my page is blank.

App.js :

```
import {
BrowserRouter as Router,
Routes,
Route
} from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
return (
  <Router>
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/" element={<MainPage/>}/>
    </Routes>
  </Router>
);
}
```

Comment: `MainPage` is not declared. Other than this, there's no issue with the code. Try killing and restarting your development server. Ensure that `MainPage` is declared and in scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Router v6 doesn't support **exact** anymore because all paths are match exactly by default

```
<Route path="/" element={<MainPage/>}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to import MainPage from its path.

```
import MainPage from "layouts/pages/index";
```

Like this.

Comment: sorry but, I already add MainPage function in the bottom of the script. I just didn't show the MainPage function script